# Android sent to php (httppost) "Undefined index: txtProvinceId "Help Me please

Tags: android, http-post

```
public class DialogSelectAmphurActivity extends Activity {

private final String TAG = "internet";
private ListView listview_province;



ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     HashMap<String, String> map;

     String strUrl =("http://192.168.1.4/test_projectEnd/amphur.php");
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_select_province_dialog);







    new AsyncDownload().execute(strUrl);

}

public String getData(String strUrl, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params){  
    String jString;
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    String sProvince_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("provinceId");
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtProvinceId",sProvince_id));

    try {
        jString =  getJsonFromUrl(strUrl, params);



            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jString);
            Log.d(TAG, jArray +","+ params);

            for(int i =0; i< jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String sAmphur_id = jObj.getString("AMPHUR_ID");
                String sAmphur_name = jObj.getString("AMPHUR_NAME");

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("amphur_id", sAmphur_id);
                map.put("amphur_name", sAmphur_name);
                myList.add(map);
                Log.d(TAG, sAmphur_id + sAmphur_name);

            }       







    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
        }

private void showProvince(){


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_province1);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, R.layout.row_layout_select_province, 
            new String[]{"amphur_id","amphur_name"}, new int[]{R.id.textView_province_id,R.id.textView_province_name});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



}


private String getJsonFromUrl(String strUrl,ArrayList<NameValuePair> params)throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strUrl);
    try {

        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
        Log.d(TAG, params+"check");
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpCon.setConnectTimeout(6*1000);
        int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "The response is" + responseCode);

        if(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            Log.d(TAG, "size" + httpCon.getContentLength());

            InputStream ins = httpCon.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins,"UTF-8"));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(line);
                response.append("\n");
                Log.d(TAG, line);

            }

            rd.close();
            return response.toString();


        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Problem reading"+ ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

private class AsyncDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(DialogSelectAmphurActivity.this, "Download", "Downloading....");
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... Params){

        String data = getData(strUrl, params);

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        pd.dismiss();
        showProvince();
    }
}


}
```

i sent txtprovinceId to php 
"Sorry for any incorrect on my conversation, my English is not good."

```
<?php

$provinceid = trim($_GET["txtProvinceId"]);

require("libs/connection_to_abc.php");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");



$strSQL = "SELECT amphur.* FROM province,amphur
WHERE province.PROVINCE_ID = amphur.PROVINCE_ID
AND province.PROVINCE_ID ='$provinceid'  ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
$resultArray = array();
while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $arrCol = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
    {
        $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
    }
    array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
}

mysql_close($link);

echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

php response in Logcat  "Undefined index: txtProvinceId in amphur.php on line 3"

Help me please ! "Sorry for any incorrect on my conversation, my English is not good."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add your `params` to the query string. You can use `URLEncodedUtils.format()` to format them easily :

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
...

private String getJsonFromUrl(String strUrl,ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
    String queryString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, null);
    URL url = new URL(strUrl + "?" + queryString);
    ...
}
```